# Scalatest - how to test println

Tags: scala, scalatest

Is there something in Scalatest that will allow me to test the output to the standard out via a `println` statement?

So far I've mainly been using `FunSuite with ShouldMatchers`.

e.g. how do we check the printed output of

```
object Hi {
  def hello() {
    println("hello world")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The usual way to test print statements on the console is to structure your program a bit differently so that you can intercept those statements. You can for example introduce an `Output` trait:

```
  trait Output {
    def print(s: String) = Console.println(s)
  }

  class Hi extends Output {
    def hello() = print("hello world")
  }
```

And in your tests you can define another trait `MockOutput` actually intercepting the calls:

```
  trait MockOutput extends Output {
    var messages: Seq[String] = Seq()

    override def print(s: String) = messages = messages :+ s
  }


  val hi = new Hi with MockOutput
  hi.hello()
  hi.messages should contain("hello world")
```

Comment: You need to add `override` to MockOutput

Comment: I like this solution a lot, @Eric is there a way to do this without having to extend `Output`. I feel `extending` a trait, where that trait is not needed in the first place, is a hack. It would make sense if the trait was already needed and we created a test impl.

Comment: The only other way to avoid extending a trait is to do what Kevin or Matthieu are advising to. That being said, I have the philosophy that building your software so that it is testable is a good design decision. When you pursue that thought you go all the way to introducing traits for *all* your IO / external systems interactions.

Comment: @eric I wouldn't say that I was **advising** redirection as a good way to write unit tests, just pointing out that it's a possibility if you e.g. needed to retrofit tests to existing code and wanted to be minimally invasive.  I'd hate to change untested code any more than was *strictly* necessary; even if it *is* for the purpose of making it easier to add said tests

Comment: `override` useful but not necessary

Answer (score 96):

If you just want to redirect console output for a limited duration, use the `withOut` and `withErr` methods defined on `Console`:

```
val stream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream()
Console.withOut(stream) {
  //all printlns in this block will be redirected
  println("Fly me to the moon, let me play among the stars")
}
```

Comment: This one is way better, no need to restructure your program for tests.

Comment: should have been the accepted answer, code should be written in 
a way its testable, but adding traits/interfaces specifically for tests is not something i am lot comfortable with.

Answer (score 6):

You can replace where println writes to by using Console.setOut(PrintStream)

```
val stream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream()
Console.setOut(stream)
println("Hello world")
Console.err.println(stream.toByteArray)
Console.err.println(stream.toString)
```

You can obviously use any type of stream you want.
You can do the same sort of thing for stderr and stdin with

```
Console.setErr(PrintStream)
Console.setIn(PrintStream)
```

Comment: Note that `Console.{setErr, setIn, setOut}` have been deprecated as of 2.11.0 (~3 years after this answer was submitted).

Comment: The new methods are Console.{withOut, withIn, withErr}