# scala test with main function

Tags: scala, scalatest

I wrote a simple Scala code to practice Scala Test:

```
object Job {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
      val sc = new SparkContext()
      println(reduceWithSum(sc))
    }

    def reduceWithSum(sc: SparkContext): MyClass = {
      val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
      val distDataValue = distData.map(MyClass(_))

      distDataValue.reduce(MyClass.sum)
    }
}
```

I know it is easy to write a test code for reduceWithSum() but it seems very hard for me to write a test code for main(). Any hint?

Here is a sample testing code I wrote:

```
class JobTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Test")
    val testSc = new SparkContext(conf)

    it should "reduce correctly" in {
      Job.reduceWithSum(testSc) shouldBe MyClass(15)
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scalatest - how to test println](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218400/scalatest-how-to-test-println)

Comment: Hey, I think it is a different question, just edit it and post for more suggestions.

Comment: is your question how to test a generic main function?

Comment: Yes, in my case if I do Job.main() shouldBe MyClass(15), I would see errors so really confused how to test for this kind of cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `main` method returns `Unit` (its signature is `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit`), so it's kind of weird to test what's "returned" by this method.

Here, you're just doing a `println`, so if you really want to check that the result is printed, you should follow the link that @JoelBerkeley gave in his comment : [Scalatest - how to test println](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218400/scalatest-how-to-test-println). However, just testing directly printed results is not a good practice : you should test what's returned by your method, but not **just** the fact that the result is printed rightly.

In most of cases, you do not need to test the `main` method because it's just the entrypoint to your program. IMHO, the `main` method should just create an instance of a class (`SparkProgram` for example) making your processing, and that's it (see [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36351853) I totally agree with). The methods in that class must be tested independently of your `main`. Your `main` method should be as short as possible : no business logic, just delegating work to classes with methods returning non-`Unit` results that could be tested.