# test a scala function with Unit return type

Tags: scala, scalatest

Is it possible to test a Unit return type function using Scala test?
If yes please give me the answer
I need my code coverage to be higher.

Comment: You can technically do it with `someFunction() == ()` but it's as meaningful as `{ someFunction(); true }`.

Comment: What does the function does and what do you want to test?

Comment: I want to test what it prints on screen

Comment: You can not _(easily)_ test that and you shouldn't. If the function only does printing it doesn't require unit tests. If the function does more than printing, then split the function in two and test the one that produces and output. - If you really really want to test what is printed, you would need to inject a different output stream to compare its contents.

Comment: How can I test a function that takes input from user inside it and performs operation on that input value

Comment: Again, you shouldn't test that. Your business logic shouldn't be populated with input / output. Your logic should just receive all it needs as arguments and return every output. Another function _(that won't be tested)_ will be in charge of doing the IO and calling that function with the logic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218400/scalatest-how-to-test-println

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following test asserts that `Hello`, `World` is getting printed on console.

```scala
type ConsoleErrors  = List[String]
type ConsoleOutputs = List[String]
test("should print hello world to console") {

  def toString(arr: Array[Byte]): List[String] = new String(arr).split("\n").toList.filter(!_.isEmpty)

  def captureConsole[T](f: => T): (T, ConsoleOutputs, ConsoleErrors) = {
    val outCapture = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    val errCapture = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    try {
      val t                   = Console.withOut(outCapture)(Console.withErr(errCapture)(f))
      val out: ConsoleOutputs = toString(outCapture.toByteArray)
      val errs: ConsoleErrors = toString(errCapture.toByteArray)
      (t, out, errs)
    }
    finally {
      outCapture.reset()
      errCapture.reset()
    }
  }

  val (_, out, errs) = captureConsole {
    println("Hello")
    println("World")
  }

  out shouldBe List("Hello", "World")
  errs shouldBe List.empty
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A function that returns Unit presumably has side effects, so you'd want to test the side effects.

Comment: I want to test that it prints something on the screen